# How to write the subquery?

Tags: database, sqlite, subquery

I am no sure how to do the following query for the following tables:

1st table - `book_type`:

```
book_type_id
book_type_code
book_type_description
```

2nd table - `books`:

```
book_id
book_type_id
book_code
book_status
book_description
```

3rd table - `sold_books`:

```
book_id
price
sold_books status (canceled, or not)
amount_of_books_sold
```

Books that have an average of `amount_of_books_sold` that is less than the average of `amount_of_books_sold` for the `book_type` that the book is in.

Do not show canceled books from `sold_books_status`.

Only these columns:

```
book_type_description, book_type_code, book_description
avg amount_of_books_sold, avg amount_of_books_sold forsook_type
```

First I tried to do all in one query. Then I tried using with statement. It didn't show me an error, but nothing was shown.
Then I tried with subqueries. No success, because I didn't know what to put in subquery.

Any ideas how to create this query or subquery in sqlite ?

Answer (score 1):

There're a few things need to be clarified:

- What's the relationship between `books` and `sold_books`?
- Does `avg_amount_of_books_sold` include `sold_book_status='canceled'`?

Assume that

- `books` and `sold_books` is 1-to-1 (This means `book_id` in `sold_books` is a primary key and also a foreign key).
- `avg_amount_of_books_sold` does not include `sold_book_status='canceled'`

Then we can do this in a few steps:

Step 1. Calculate `avg_amount_of_books_sold` (please remove `where...` clause if canceled books are included.)

```sql
select avg(amount_of_books_sold) as avg_amount_of_books_sold
  from sold_books
 where sold_book_status <> 'canceled';
```

Step 2. Join all three tables to get those columns you need.

```sql
select t.book_type_description,
       t.book_type_code,
       b.book_description,
       s.amount_of_books_sold
  from book_type t
  join books b
    on t.book_type_id = b.book_type_id
  join sold_books s
    on b.book_id = s.book_id
 where s.sold_book_status <> 'canceled';
```

Step 3. Put the above two queries in CTE sub-query and then compares `amount_of_books_sold` and `avg_amount_of_books_sold` in `where` clause to include only `amount_of_books_sold < avg_amount_of_books_sold`.

```sql
with cte_avg_amount_of_books_sold as (
select avg(amount_of_books_sold) as avg_amount_of_books_sold
  from sold_books
 where sold_book_status <> 'canceled'),
cte_sold_books_not_canceled as (
select t.book_type_description,
       t.book_type_code,
       b.book_description,
       s.amount_of_books_sold
  from book_type t
  join books b
    on t.book_type_id = b.book_type_id
  join sold_books s
    on b.book_id = s.book_id
 where s.sold_book_status <> 'canceled')
select t.*, a.*
  from cte_sold_books_not_canceled t, cte_avg_amount_of_books_sold a
 where t.amount_of_books_sold < a.avg_amount_of_books_sold;
```

Please note that if the relationship between `books` and `sold_books` is not 1-to-1 but 1-to-many, then you need to have a rule about either how to pick a row from `sold_books` for a specific `book_id` or how to aggregate the information in `sold_books` to `book_id` level.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the explanation too. It really helped me to see how to think when writing a query.

Comment: JHH, I write the query in a similar way as you did. You sir are a rockstar. Thank you for showing the syntax for with clause, that is not easy to find online. When I was looking up for it, it kept showing with recursive or for other db. And thank you for mentioning about relationships between tables. It really put this in a whole new light for me.